# Laravel 5, Mail:: with later() not working

Tags: laravel

`Mail` with `later()` is not working with the time that I give it as parameter.

```
$when = $final_new_days_count;//Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5);
Mail::to($user)
    ->later($when, new Expired($user, $when));

I'm receiving the email just when I execute the code that calls `Mail::`

With `dd($when);` I get:

Carbon {#766 ▼
  +"date": "2019-07-22 23:59:59.229078"
  +"timezone_type": 3
  +"timezone": "UTC"
}

Actually, in the email view I'm sending this:

<p>Now: {{ \Carbon\Carbon::now() }}</p>
<p>When: {{ $when->date }}</p>
```

And I'm seeing in the email that I receive:

```
Now: 2019-07-19 16:18:23
When: 2019-07-22 23:59:59.315271
```

So why is not working `later`?

EDIT: In my .env I have:

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

I can't change that, some other functions need it.

EDIT 2: Well, I tested with QUEUE_DRIVER=database but didn't know that php artisan queue:work has to be running alltime. I can't have this running all time :S

Comment: "I can't have this running all time" There are ways of configuring your server to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Laravel Mail `later` functionality needs a queue to be running for it to work. By default your `QUEUE_DRIVER` is set to `sync`. This means that it will fire it right away.

Use the `redis` or `database` queue so it can queue the job for a later.

```
QUEUE_DRIVER=redis
```

If you dont want to run `php artisan queue:work` the entire time in your command line I would advise using a process manager like Supervisor.

Docs on the queue process and process manager:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#running-the-queue-worker

Installing Supervisor:

https://cloudwafer.com/blog/how-to-install-and-configure-supervisor-on-ubuntu-16-04/

This will allow the `php artisan queue:work` to be run as a background process.

The following config will work if you decide to use supervisor:

```
 `[program:laravel-worker]
  process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
  command=php /path/to/artisan queue:work
  autostart=true
  autorestart=true
  numprocs=8
  redirect_stderr=true
  stdout_logfile=/home/forge/app.com/worker.log`
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll check "Supervisor"

Comment: This was the hint I needed to check the status of my Supervisor queue job in my hosting account - thank you @Devin.